# How to loop a JS path in the chrome dev tools console?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

Context: I need to obtain information from a bunch of data in a web app. I do not use API because obtaining an API key would be too much of an issue. Therefore I decided to start using the chrome dev tools also as you'll see I am a complete beginner with this tool but recognize it's utility.

**Problem:** I found the table element that holds all the information that I want in my case I only want one column of that table. (I obtain the JS Path with that purpose) I read the elements in the dev tools and the syntax is the next one(copying the JS path):

```
document.querySelector (#WorkflowSchemes > div > div.legacy-jira-fe-module.toggle-wrap.expanded > div.mod-content > table > body > tr:nth-child(1) > td > strong")
```

Pasting the obtained JS path and adding the .innerText into the console of chrome gives me one of the 200 text elements that I need. What I need to do is iterate the **(tr:nth-child(1))** node. To end up grabbing all the 200 text elements I need.

**What I have at the moment:**

```
var cycle =function (cycleCommand){while(let i = 1 < 200){
  console.log(document.querySelector (#WorkflowSchemes > div > div.legacy-jira-fe-module.toggle-wrap.expanded > div.mod-content > table > body > tr:nth-child("i") > td > strong").innerText
 }
```

```js
var cycle = function (cycleTest)
for (let index = 0; index < 200: index++){
document.querySelector("WorkflowSchemes > div > div.legacy-jira-fe-module.togle-wrap.expanded > div.mod-content > table > tbody> tr:nth-child (("index"))  > td > strong")
}
```

I hope the problem is understandable please let me know if you know a way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: *one of the 200 text elements* According to your selector, that would mean you have 200 tables, right? *I only want one column of that table* Your selector is only looking at one **row** of that table.

Comment: @connexo I see what you mean but no the element I want to loop corresponds to each row. e.g.: 
This one you can see it has the tr:nth-child(1) it corresponds to the first row and adding the (td > strong ) brings me the exact element I wanted. 
document.querySelector (#WorkflowSchemes > div > div.legacy-jira-fe-module.toggle-wrap.expanded > div.mod-content > table > body > tr:nth-child(1) > td > strong")To bring the element I wanted from the second row I would change the number in tr:nth-child() to 2 having: tr:nth-child(2) that puts me in the second row

Comment: @connexo -  adding the td > strong gives me exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a collection of all the `strong` elements in the table that are direct children of `td` elements in the `tbody`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#WorkflowSchemes > div > div.legacy-jira-fe-module.toggle-wrap.expanded > div.mod-content > table > tbody > tr > td > strong')
```

is going to give you an array-like list of the nodes.